# How to generate weekly report in SQL2012

Tags: sql-server

I've to generate a weekly report every Monday in SQL Server 2012.
Example: Suppose, I start today(06/19/2017-Monday), so my current query 
should fetch me results from past. Now, when I run the query again next 
week

(06/26/2017-Monday), it should fetch me the data from
(06/20/2017-Tuesday on wards) the Database. I hope this is clear.

I've the below query, what do I need to add in this to make it generate 
weekly reports.

[image: [MySQLCODE]]

Comment: Nothing attached?

Comment: instead of linking to an image of your query, you should post the query as text.

Comment: And you should start using ANSI-92 style joins...they have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: U should see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any attached SQL code as stated in your question. Either way I will show you how I have a similar report set up using variables and the SQL "between" word.

```
        DECLARE @dateRangeStart datetime, 
        @dateRangeEnd datetime 
    SET @dateRangeStart = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())-7, 0)
    set @dateRangeEnd = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()),  0)

Select ...<your query>
Where <the column name that holds dates> date_created between @dateRangeStart and @dateRangeEnd
```

Now the query I entered will find all items from 7 days ago at 12am to today at 12am. So if you ran it on a Monday it will have data from (past Monday @ 12am until today Monday at 12am). So you may need to adjust the time you use for your between. If you add your code I or someone else may be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks Kram_Koorbse. I'll try this and advise.